# Permissions VSCode and Linux/Apache

Tags: linux, apache, visual-studio-code, user-permissions

Here is the problem I'm facing:

I use Linux Mint 20.3 Cinnamon.

I have user called `user-test` which is in the group `user-test` - `user-test:user-test`.
I have a directory with WordPress project in var/www/project .
VSCode, that uses the user `user-test` and Apache that uses `www-data` in the group `www-data`.

When I open the project with VScode, if I change the project folder owner to www-data, every time I try to save a file it shows this notification: [Notification - Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej5eT.png)
If I change the user to: `user-test:user-test` I have a problem with every action I want to take in the project.
For example: I'm not able to upload files, update plugins or the system /in the admin panel of WordPress/.

So whenever I want to update/upgrade or upload something in the admin panel I Need to change the user to `www-data:www-data` and whenever I want to change something with VSCode I need to change the user to `user-test:user-test`.
I don't want to change the permissions of the folder to 0777 or other than 0755, because they are automatically deployed to a live server after the changes are pushed to Git.

I can't remember for a solution for this problem. The only one I do is to set the VSCode to open with www-data by default, but If somebody has a better solution I would appreciate your advices.

Comment: this is a common issue, simply add the user to www-data group. FYI permissions are not pushed to git

Answer (score 0):

You could change git config to ignore permission changes with

```
git config core.fileMode false
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode